# Java criteria restrictions sum of columns lower than value

Tags: java, sql, criteria, restrictions

Hi I've a question about converting a simple SQL statement into a java hibernate restriction.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT a + b FROM col WHERE a + b < 10
```

When I try to convert this to a criteria I get:

```
Criteria criteria = createCriteria();
criteria.createAlias("col","col").add(Restrictions.lt("a+b",10));
```

But it seems like the string `"a+b"` is not accepted. How do I have to write my restriction?

Comment: that should work.. which database are you using?

Comment: I have my own database. But when I execute the script above I get this exeption:Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: a+b of: col

Comment: I think Joe was asking what flavour of database server you are using. MySQL? postgresql? Oracle? MS SQLServer?

Comment: O sorry, I'm using postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because Hibernate is trying to resolve *a+b* as your entity's property, and you get

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: a+b
```

There are few possible solutions:

**1st: sql restriction:**

```
//Hibernate 4.x
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("col_a+col_b < ?", Integer.valueOf(10), org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER);

// Hibernate 3.x
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("col_a+col_b < ?", Integer.valueOf(10),       org.hibernate.Hibernate.INTEGER);
```

There is one issue that you must use column names instead of property names.

**2nd: Formula:**

Add to your entity a virtual column using *@Formula* annotation:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Formula("a + b")
private int aSumB;
```

and use it as a standard property:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("aSumB", Integer.valueOf(10));
```

**3rd Custom Criteria:**

If you are using it a lot consider to create custom criteria by implementing *org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion*