# Derive date from two columns using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have `START_TIME (timestamp)` and `AVAILABLE_PERIOD (number)` columns in my Table.

Is there a way I can query the table with a condition like `current_time < (START_TIME + AVAILABLE_PERIOD)` using `hibernate criteria`?

Same question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303635/cast-date-to-ms-to-add-long-value-of-duration-with-criteria). But no answer.

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18208519/672841?

Comment: The problem with my situation is, my `START_TIME` and `AVAILABLE_PERIOD` is **not** in same data type.

Comment: what data types are they? And I think you should be able to do any conversion you do with SQL by calling SQLcriteria method,

Comment: `START_TIME` in date format and `AVAILABLE_PERIOD` in integer

Comment: Can you do what you are trying to achieve using SQL? If so passing that SQL to sqlCriteria should work. If you can't do that using plain SQL I don't think you will be able to do that using hibernate. But then again, I'm not a Hibernate expert.

Comment: thank for the comments. using SQL functions will make the criteria DBMS specific here.